# Prestashop jquery Count Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I have a mistake in my prestashop page.

The countdown jquery code seems correct to me but the it doesn't contdown. The data in the product page appears like this:

[image: image from browser]

My code is:

```html
<!-- START product countdown -->
{if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
    {if isset($product->specificPrice) && isset($product->specificPrice.to) && isset($product->specificPrice.from)}
        {if ($smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' <= $product->specificPrice.to && $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >= $product->specificPrice.from)}

            <div class="prod_countdown_area">
                <div class="prod_page_countdown" data-date="{$product->specificPrice.to|date_format} {$product->specificPrice.to|date_format:'%H:%M:%S'}"></div>
                {literal}
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function() {
                            $('.prod_page_countdown').countdown({
                                render: function(data) {
                                $(this.el).html("<div class='prod_count_label'>{/literal}{l s='Expires:'}{literal}</div><div class='countdown_list days'><span class='countdown_digit'>" +
                                        this.leadingZeros(data.days, 3) + "</span><span class='countdown_label'>{/literal}{l s='days'}{literal}</span></div><div class='countdown_list hrs'><span class='countdown_digit'>" + 
                                        this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + "</span><span class='countdown_label'>{/literal}{l s='hrs'}{literal}</span></div><div class='countdown_list min'><span class='countdown_digit'>" + 
                                        this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + "</span><span class='countdown_label'>{/literal}{l s='min'}{literal}</span></div><div class='countdown_list sec'><span class='countdown_digit'>" + 
                                        this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + "</span><span class='countdown_label'>{/literal}{l s='sec'}{literal}</span></div>");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                {/literal}

            </div>

        {/if}
    {/if}
{/if}
<!-- END product countdown -->
</script>
{/literal}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.
Pedro

Comment: maybe that : there is two {/literal} and one {literal}, same problem for </script>

Comment: thank you but it bellongs to another code.

Comment: well, just be sure, that they don't cross each other :    {a}content{/a}{a}content 2{/a}  ll work, but {a} content {a}content 2 {/a}{/a} ll fail